# Automated placement of points/landmarks on shape outline using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computational-geometry

I'm just beginning with Image analysis in MATLAB.

My goal is to do an automated image segmention on images of plant leaves.
I have had reasonable success here thanks to multiple online resources.

The current objective, the reason why I'm placing this question here, is to able to place 25 equidistant points along each half of the margin/outline of leaf, like described in following image:

[image: Leaf]

For the script to be able to recognize each half of the leaf, user can put two points within the GUI. One of these user-defined points will be on the base of leaf and the other on tip of leaf. It would be even better if a script would be able to automatically recognize these two features of the leaf.

For the output, I would like a plain text format file containing image coordinate of each point.

I'm not asking for a ready made script here, but looking for a starting point.

---

One way I think this can be done is by linearizing/open up the outline in such a way that it becomes a straight line. This can be done by treating any of user placed point/landmark as breakpoint. Once a linear outline is obtained it can again be broken into two halves at other user defined point and now points can be placed. One point to bear in mind here is that the placement of points for each half should start from the end that corresponds to the same breakpoint/user-defined point in each half. Now these straight lines can be superimposed on original image for reconstruction.

Thank you very much.

Parashar

Comment: Do you have the segmented leaf blob? If so, could you share, link up here?